# FastReport4: Refresh Dataset

Tags: delphi, fastreport

My `Report.ShowPreparedReport` didn't recognize a new addition to my frxDBDataset.

So, I was building 1 report using TfrxDBDataset linked to a TVirtualTable.
Previously only 10 fields stated in Report1.fr3 and it works well.

- I do the SaveAs from Report1.fr3 to Report2.fr3 in designer mode
- Get back to my Delphi and add 1 new field "tec" in my TVirtualTable
- Go back again in ReportDesigner (file Report2.fr3) and see that my new "tec" field is listed in Data tree.
- Add the "tec" field to the report.
- Preview while on designer and it was normal.
- Run the program and call to preview report, it says "field 'tec' cannot be found" or something like that.

Anyone got solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please Try.

```
TVirtualTable.Refresh;
frxDBDataset.FieldAliases.Clear;
```

When you clear aliases then call Designer
FastReport automatically updates aliases.

That was the perfect solution for me.